# how to encode servlet response to base64?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, encoding, base64

I was trying to send the images in servlet to ajax call but its showing some characters in my browser instead.
my question is how to encode servlet response in `base64`.
I have an image as response.

Servlet code :

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
ServletOutputStream out;  
out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\Astro\\html5up-arcana (1)\\images\\1.jpg");

BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
int ch =0; ;  
while((ch=bin.read())!=-1) {  
    bout.write(ch);  
}
```

Ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nxt').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'DisplayImage',
            data : {
                userName : 'Hi'
            },
            success : function(result) {
                $('#gallery-overlay').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+result+'"/>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- **Using `java.util.Base64` JDK8**

  ```
  byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead = 0;
  String strFileContents;
  while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
      bout.write(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(contents), bytesRead);
  }
  ```
- **Using `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`, *Note that: The Oracle says that the `sun.*` packages are not part of the supported, public interface. Therefore try to prevent using this method***

  ```
  sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder= new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
  byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead = 0;
  String strFileContents;
  while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
      bout.write(encoder.encode(contents).getBytes());
  }
  ```
- **Using  `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`**

  ```
  byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
  int bytesRead = 0;
  while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
      bout.write(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(contents), bytesRead);
  }
  ```

Comment: I think i need to increase byte capacity because image is displaying partially.

Comment: Poor answer. Partial encoding isn't supported by Base64 (as confirmed by OP's problem "Image is displaying partially"). Nonetheless, a fat downvote for `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` for reasons mentioned in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: yes, however it was the essayist way before jdk8. that method works fine. so no need any support to use this method.